# Capital gains and dividends tax arbitrage

Tags: arbitrage

There is a statement in Paul Wimott Introduce Quantitative Finance:

> Often capital gains due to the rise in a stock price are taxed differently from a dividend, which is often treated as income. Some people can make a lot of  risk-free money by exploiting tax 'inconsistencies'

Can anyone give an example how this exploits work?

Answer (score 1):

A prime example of tax arbitrage is described in the paper [Cross-Border Investing with Tax Arbitrage: The Case of German Dividend Tax Credits](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/mcdonald/htm/rfs14_3_2.pdf) by Robert L. McDonald (excerpt below). In this case, dividend income can be used to gain tax credits and as a result, the next day dividend drop exceeds the dividend value.

> German dividends typically carry a tax credit which makes the dividend
>   worth 42.86% more to a taxable German shareholder than to a tax-exempt
>   or foreign shareholder. This results  in  a  penalty  for  foreign 
>   investors  who  buy  and  hold  German  dividend-paying stocks. I
>   document that, as a result of the credit, the ex-day drop exceeds the
>   dividend by more than one-half of the tax credit, and show that
>   futures and option prices embed more  than  one-half  of  the  tax 
>   credit.  The  existence  of  the  credit  creates  opportunities for 
>   cross-border  tax  arbitrage—in  which  foreign  holders  of  German 
>   stock  transfer  the dividend to German shareholders—and implies that
>   it is tax efficient for foreign investors to hold derivatives rather
>   than investing directly in German stocks.

Another arbitrage strategy used by non-financial firms that does not involve cross border transactions is described in the paper [How Prevalent is Tax Arbitrage? Evidence from the Market for Municipal Bonds](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/austan.goolsbee/research/munis.pdf), by M. Erickson et. al.:

> [Non-financial firms] hold municipal bonds tax-free
>   while simultaneously borrowing and deducting the interest expenses
>   from their taxable income.